# How to create ROOT histograms out of a 3 column .dat file?

Tags: physics, root-framework

I currently have a .dat file with format:

> Format: Log(10,s22th13)   deltacp   chi^2
>
> -4 0 0.098127
>
> -4 4 0.093642
>
> -4 8 0.089323
>
> -4 12 0.085185
>
> -4 16 0.081242  ....

How would I create a plot using ROOT, keeping the labels specified at the top of the .dat file?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to read your file using `TTree` class:

```
    TTree *T = new TTree("ntuple","data from csv file");
    Long64_t nlines = T->ReadFile("data.csv");
    printf("found %lld points\n",nlines);
```

Your header will be used as names for branches. Then you can draw/save histograms using something like that:

```
    TH1F *hist = new TH1F("name","title", nbinsx,xlow,xup);
    T->Draw("branch>>name","","");
```